# Change directory for screenshot from applescript

Tags: applescript

I am making a script that takes a picture of whoever opens it by taking a screenshot of PhotoBooth. However, I do not know how to change the directory of the screenshoot, because I just started AppleScript. For example, I want it to go the folder 
    /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/AllFolders/Folder1/Folder2
How would I do that?

Heres my code:

```
tell application "Photo Booth"

    activate
    set volume output volume 0
    tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Photo 
Booth" to false

end tell

property N : 0
set N to N + 1
delay 0.1
set picPath to ((POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "Picture_" & N & ".png") as string
do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of 
picPath

tell application "Photo Booth"
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: If you've made _Photo Booth_ invisible, then `screencapture` won't see it and you'll just have a screen grab of your screen with no _Photo Booth_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out without using iSightCapture!

First instead of making photo booth invisible, I close it immediately after taking a screenshot. Thanks @CJK for that bugfix.

To answer the problem, I found that the code:

```
set picPath to ((POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "Picture_" & N & ".png") as string
do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of picPath
```

was the answer to this problem. 
I got rid of the N addition to simplify it.
Instead of

```
POSIX path of (path to desktop)
```

I changed the path.

```
set picPath to (POSIX path of "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/folder1/folder2/nameoffile ") & ".png" as string
```

This worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Download isightcapture utility for Mac (Google search, thanks to axel@intergalatic.de to made this a freeware !), and store the file somewhere on your Mac, for instance in your Documents folder.

Use this shell command in Applescript via 'do shell script' instruction :

```
do shell script "~/Documents/isightcapture ~/Desktop/Photo.jpg"
```

The '~/Documents' is the path to your isightcapture command : here in your Documents folder.

The '~/Desktop/Photo.jpg' stores the picture made on Desktop with name Photo.jpg. Of course it could be any of your other folders !

There are several parameters  for that command (isightcapture -h will give yo more options)

-t option to specify the photo format : jpg (by default) , png, tiff, bmp

-w and -h to define picture size

```
Do shell script  ~/Documents/isightcapture -w 320 -h 240 -t png ~/Documents/Folder1/P1.png
```

This script take a photo and store it a png format in file P1.png in folder Folder1 in my Documents folder. The picture size is 320 x 240.

Note : this utility works since Snowleopard (OS 10.6) and I tested it up to OS 10.12. I don't see any reason why it would no work on next versions.